# D365 C# Plugin: service.RetrieveMultiple Erroring Out no Matter What QueryString I Give It

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I've been writing D365 plugins for years and haven't ever encountered what I'm encountering now. No matter how simplest and correct the query I am giving `service.RetrieveMultiple(query)`, I keep receiving the following error:

> Error retrieving mapping results: Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.
>
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]:
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Fault Detail is
> equal to Exception details: ErrorCode: 0x80040224 Message: Object
> reference not set to an instance of an object. TimeStamp:
> 2024-01-23T18:09:24.0021743Z OriginalException: PluginExecution
> ExceptionSource: PluginExecution
> -- ).

My query is much more complex than the following, however, I dumbed down the query expression to test the `service.RetrieveMultiple()` to test something that should ABSOLUTLEY work. The following is the code:

```
private Mapping RetrieveMapping(IOrganizationService service, Guid entityId, ITracingService tracer, string recordId, string entity, string mappingName)
{
    //Create a query expression specifying the link entity alias and the columns of the link entity that you want to return  
    var query = new QueryExpression();
    query.EntityName = "account";
    query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet();
    query.ColumnSet.Columns.Add("name");

    tracer.Trace($"QueryByAttribute EntityName:  {query.EntityName}");
    tracer.Trace($"QueryByAttribute ColumnSet:  {string.Join(", ", query.ColumnSet.Columns)}");

    try
    {
        // Execute the query against the organization service and store the results
        EntityCollection results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        tracer.Trace("Retrieved Mapping Results from CRM");
        foreach (Entity record in results.Entities) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"name:{record.GetAttributeValue<string>("name")}"); 
        }
    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log or handle the exception
        tracer.Trace($"Error retrieving mapping results: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Any extra eyes would help. I've been pulling my hair out for a while now over this. Again, no matter what queryString and how simple as seen above, `service.RetrieveMultiple()` with the noted error evertime. My tracers show that all the values in the query expression have values and not null.

Regards.

Comment: It's always the simplest things that get overlooked. `service` was `null` after doing some further testing. So this `IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)serviceProvider.GetService (typeof(IOrganizationService));` needed to be changed to this `IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);`